# HTML Link not redirecting correctly - its navigating to www.oldpage.com/http://www.google.com?

Tags: html, hyperlink

Any one got any ideas why this is happening?

My html quite clearly is

```
<a href="www.google.com">www.google.com</a>
```

However, when I click it, I am navigated to the incorrect URL.

In my case to -- http://localhost:8000/profile/1/www.google.com

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then the link is actually working.  But the URL is wrong.  You're using this URL:

```
"www.google.com"
```

But a browser has no way of knowing that this is another website.  Structurally it's no different than, say, this:

```
"www.index.html"
```

Which is a perfectly valid name for a resource on your website.

To tell the browser that this should go to another website, include the protocol:

```
"http://www.google.com"
```

Or at least the `//` at the start to default to whatever the current page's protocol is:

```
"//www.google.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL You are using is

`www.google.com`

Which will not redirect to the site, You have to use it like this:

`https://www.google.com`

Ex.:

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Working URL</a><br>
<a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">Not Working URL</a>
```